# jQuery click does not work but toggle does

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is doing nothing:

```
$("#nav li ul li").click(function(){
  $(this).find('ul:first').css({
    visibility: "visible"
  });
});
```

This is working (showing and hiding):

```
$("#nav li ul li").toggle(function() {
  $(this).find('ul:first').css({
    visibility: "visible"
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).find('ul').css({
    visibility: "hidden"
  });
});
```

I want to get the first one to work, I don't want it to toggle.

Comment: Please post your HTML, and whenever possible, also include a jsFiddle.net link.

Comment: Oh, and the use of toggle() you're attempting was removed from jQuery not long ago.

Comment: Need more code to help, but typically prefer to use .on('click', function(){})

Comment: Are you running your script in $(document).ready function?

Comment: Got it to work, the problem was this a few lines underneath:

$('html').click(function() {
       $("#nav li ul li").find('ul').css({
                display:"none"
        });
});

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$("#nav li ul li").click(function(){
  $(this).find('ul').first().css("visibility","visible");
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this code sample results in a different behavior than the questioner's first example?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I am using the first as a function and OP is using it in selector. In many case like in find the :first is not workable(In many cases). This is my personal experience.

Comment: That's why I asked, there is no functional difference between applying the `:first` selector and chaining into the `first()` method. In theory, if the questioner's first sample fails to work for him, so will your code.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi hmm, Right. And thanks to focus me on elaborating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.ghost{visibility:hidden;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#nav li ul li").click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first').toggleClass('ghost')
});
```